# Java JTDS to SQL server 2000

Tags: java, sql, jtds

ive got a method that connects to sql server using JTDS

```
String url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.12.123;instance=server-e61t7rvb;DatabaseName=test";
     String driver = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
    String userName = "sa";
    String password = "hello";

                Class.forName(driver);
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
        System.out.println("Connected to the database!!! Getting table list...");
        DatabaseMetaData dbm = conn.getMetaData();
        rs = dbm.getTables(null, null, "%", new String[] { "TABLE" });
        while (rs.next())  System.out.println(rs.getString("TABLE_NAME"));
```

using this i can connect fine to SQL 2008 but when i change it to a SQL 2000 server i get "server has no instance named "
for the instance name i am running

```
select @@servername
```

note that i can use the instance name to log into the server from my computer using sql management studio.

any help much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removed the instance parameter and it worked fine